# Video Background in Mobile Browsers

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, mobile-browser, tubular

I'm trying to make new web-site that background has a video.
I found a JS library: [tubular](http://www.seanmccambridge.com/tubular/)

This plugin working as expected in my desktop browser. (Checked on : Chrome,Safari,Firefox)

But, This NOT working in mobile browsers.
I tried in (Nexus 5, HTC M8).
Both devices are not responding for video background.
Anyone there who knows the solution for this issue or some alternative library that I can use?

Answer (score 0):

I suspect this is a problem with the video background not autoplaying on a mobile browser.  This is by design though, it is a mechanism that prevents autoplaying videos from using up bandwidth unnecessarily.